# Unity 2D: How to decrement static int in while loop using deltaTime

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my Player script I set a static int called boost to be used from any script.

I have a few boost pick up coins through out the game, when the player gets one it fills their boost tank by +1

You need a min of 3 boost coins to start boosting in the vehicle. When the player is using boost, the boost will last for about as many seconds as many boost coins collected. Using the boost should decrement the boost tank.

Player Script

```
public static int boost;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherObject)
{
    if (otherObject.tag == "Boost")
    {
        boost++;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlaySound(BoostSound, 5.7F);
        Destroy(otherObject.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Button call code

```
public void BoostButton()
{
  StartCoroutine("Use_VehicleBoost");
}
```

Booster code that a button calls.

```
IEnumerator Use_VehicleBoost()
{
    //   Check which boost package player picked
    int boostLevel = SecurePlayerPrefs.GetInt("BoostLevel");
    if (boostLevel == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Boost Level: None");
        yield return null;
    }
    else if (boostLevel == 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Boost Level: 1");

        float aceleRate = 400, maxFWD = -2500;
        while (Player.boost >= 3)
        {
            vehicleController.GetComponent<CarMovement>().accelerationRate += aceleRate;
            vehicleController.GetComponent<CarMovement>().maxFwdSpeed += maxFWD;

            //  Meant to slowly take one point/ Time second away from boost tank            //  Problem is here ----->>>
            Player.boost = Player.boost - Mathf.RoundToInt(Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
        if (Player.boost <= 0)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

Problem is here in this line

```
Player.boost = Player.boost - Mathf.RoundToInt(Time.deltaTime);
```

It is supposed to be decrementing with seconds from `Player.boost`. For example if player collects 3 boost coins then boost is active when used it will last for 3 seconds before turning off.

Not exactly sure on what to do here. They told me that in the while loop the `deltaTime` stays at value 0 because its stuck in one frame? Am I supposed to start a timer variable? Thank you.

Comment: why not add to a float variable, when that variable >= to 1, subtract 1 from both your Player.Boost, and from the variable itself?

Comment: Another thing to think about time.deltaTime is a really small float something like 0.002 depending on your frame rate, so rounding that makes it 0.

Comment: I want the boost to last in seconds from the amount in the `static int boost`. I cant subtract -1 because the user can get up to 10 seconds of boost.

Comment: So `Time.deltaTime` never reaches longer than 1 frame before getting reset?

Comment: @WorkerHead no it shouldnt get longer then 1 ever, unless you have really bad frame rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not exactly sure on what to do here. They told me that in the while
>   loop the deltaTime stays at value 0 because its stuck in one frame? Am
>   I supposed to start a timer variable?

Yes, I did say that but you have fixed the one frame issue with `yield return null;` which let's the loop to wait one frame therefore giving `Time.deltaTime`  chance to change. Even with that being fixed, there is still 0 issue I told you but because `while (Player.boost >= 3)` is still true. That is true because `Mathf.RoundToInt(Time.deltaTime);` is returning zero. You can verify this with `Debug.Log(Mathf.RoundToInt(Time.deltaTime))`.

If `Player.boost` type is an `int`, change it to a `float` type, to gradually decrease it with `Time.deltaTime` directly:

```
while (Player.boost >= 3)
{
    vehicleController.GetComponent<CarMovement>().accelerationRate += aceleRate;
    vehicleController.GetComponent<CarMovement>().maxFwdSpeed += maxFWD;

    // Meant to slowly take one point/ Time second away from boost tank          
    Player.boost = Player.boost - Time.deltaTime;
    //OR  Player.boost -= Time.deltaTime;
    yield return null;
}
```

If `Player.boost` type is an `int` but you don't want to change it to `float`, remove the `Time.deltaTime` as that's used for `float` values then do the waiting with `WaitForSeconds`. With this you can subtract one from boost after each `WaitForSeconds` call.

```
while (Player.boost >= 3)
{
    vehicleController.GetComponent<CarMovement>().accelerationRate += aceleRate;
    vehicleController.GetComponent<CarMovement>().maxFwdSpeed += maxFWD;

    // Meant to slowly take one point/ Time second away from boost tank          
    Player.boost = Player.boost - 1;
    //OR  Player.boost -= 1;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
}
```